# Does eslint-plugin-react-hooks displays the errors on the code itself or just the terminal when starting?

Tags: reactjs, visual-studio-code, react-hooks, vscode-extensions, eslint-plugin-react-hooks

When using the package:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/eslint-plugin-react-hooks
Is it supposed to add visual yellow underline warnings on react component while using vscode?
Or that just add the warnings when you are running the app on the terminal log?

Mine only display those hook warnings on the log and I am wondering how to enable that in the code itself

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made it work installing the ESLint vscode extension

Answer (score 1):

That won't work in vscode however, if you add a linter extension it should do the job you want to do.

I couldn't suggest one as I don't use one but have a search in the extensions tab of vscode, there's bound to be something that suits.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).